# Usercaught syntaxError:"undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, mern, google-sa360-api

I am creating an authentication system using MERN stack.
I already have completed 70% of my work.Till yesterday it was working flawlessly, but from today morning my app doesn't render in browser and show it in the console

I am trying to solve it during the whole day but it's not working

If anyone help me with it I will be grateful to him,,,,[console view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a2wM.png)

Render the app on browser

Comment: Please, post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It means that, somehow, you passed `undefined` as an argument to `JSON.parse()` which only accepts valid JSON values. As to how, we definitely don't know, and never will unless you show us your code in not an image, but a minimal reproducible example.